# Use of invoking constructor within same constructor

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyClass();
    }
    public MyClass() {
        new MyClass();
    }
}
```

In above code, a constructor is invoked within the same constructor.

The Output of above code is famous `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, because a constructor is invoked until the error occurs.

My question is what are the real scenarios in which invoking a constructor within the same constructor is useful?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I personally feel it's of no real use, until and unless you have another constructor which takes parameter, then calling them inside another constructor makes sense.

Comment: When the logic wants it so. Maybe there is a `Node` constructor which automatically wants to create a hierarchy for the freshly generated note, and though is calling another overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure one could invent a scenario, but making constructors recursive is not generally a useful thing to do.  Generally speaking, when a constructor calls `new` on the same class, it is a mistake.

---

Here is a contrived example in which we use recursion to construct a list of N copies of the same value.

```
   public class MyList {
       private int value;
       private MyList next;

       public MyList(int value, int length) {
           this.value = value;
           if (length > 1) {
              next = new MyList(value, length - 1);
           }
       }
   }
```

(And, yes, there are flaws in this approach ...)

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful in situations where recursive loop is broken at some point  - for example with `if` statement:

```
class LinkedList {

    Object value;
    LinkedList next;

    public LinkedList(final Iterator<?> iterator) {
        this.value = iterator.next();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            this.next = new LinkedList(iterator);
        }
    }
}
```

This will call constructor recursively as long as there are elements available in iterator.